# class overrule when two classes assigned to one div

Tags: class, css, html

I was creating a `<div>` tag in which I wanted to apply two classes for a `<div>` tag which would be a thumbnail gallery. One class for its position and the other class for its style. This way I could apply the style, I was having some strange results which brought me to a question.

Can two classes be assigned to a `<div>` tag? If so, which one overrules the other one or which one has priority?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Multiple classes can be assigned to a div.  Just separate them in the class name with spaces like this:

```
<div class="rule1 rule2 rule3">Content</div>
```

This div will then match any style rules for three different class selectors: `.rule1`, `.rule2` and `.rule3`.

CSS rules are applied to objects in the page that match their selectors in the order they are encountered in the style sheet and if there is a conflict between two rules (more than one rule trying to set the same attribute), then [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) determines which rule takes precedence.

If the CSS specificity is the same for the conflicting rules, then the later one (the one defined later in the stylesheet or in the later stylesheet) takes precedence.  The order of the class names on the object itself does not matter.  It is the order of the style rules in the style sheet that matters if the CSS specificity is the same.

So, if you had styles like this:

```
.rule1 {
    background-color: green;
}

.rule2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then, since both rules match the div and have exactly the same CSS specificity, then the second rule comes later so it would have precedence and the background would be red.

---

If one rule had a higher CSS specificity (`div.rule1` scores higher than `.rule2`):

```
div.rule1 {
    background-color: green;
}

.rule2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then, it would take precedence and the background color here would be green.

---

If the two rules don't conflict:

```
.rule1 {
    background-color: green;
}

.rule2 {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Then, both rules will be applied.

Comment: +1 Another great link explaining CSS specificity: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-cascade/

Comment: the answer below I think is more correct if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @nagates - Which answer do you think is more correct and why?  There are many answers "below" so I don't know which one you were referring to and don't know why you think it's "more correct".  I'm happy to improve or clarify my answer if you can explain your thoughts.

Comment: jfriend00: the answer by @erez-sason below is the one he is referring to. This is odd because I thought it worked like you have outlined, but his examples clearly work the way he describes. I wonder if there is a distinction between embedded styles and linked styles.

Comment: @AdamMcCormick - My answer already contains the info from that answer as one of the examples I provide: ***Then, since both rules match the div and have exactly the same CSS specificity, then the second rule comes later so it would have precedence and the background would be red.***.  I show several possible scenarios and explain them all, not just one scenario.  The OP was not specific with their code so I went for the general explanation that covers multiple options and includes the simplest option.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was clearly reading a conflict where there was none. Sorry

Answer (score 40):

Actually, the class that defined last in the css - is applied on your div.

check it out:

### red last in css

```css
.blue{ color: blue; }
.red { color: red;  }
```

```html
<div class="blue red">blue red</div>
<div class="red blue">red blue</div>
```

vs

### blue last in css

```css
.red { color: red;  }
.blue{ color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="blue red">blue red</div>
<div class="red blue">red blue</div>
```

Comment: This is a much better answer. The accepted answer is misleading.

Comment: indeed, order inside a `class` attribute is beaten by an order in the classes declaration inside a generated CSS table and that is confusing, confusing... BUT! modify the rule as `div.red { color: red;  }` and it will have the greater specificity even if was defined earlier.

Answer (score 4):

If you asking about they have same property then as per the CSS rule it's take the last statement.

```
<div class="red green"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red{
 color:red;
}
.green{
 color:green;
}
```

As per the above example it's take the last statement as per css tree which is **.green**.

Answer (score 3):

The class that is defined last in the CSS have priority, if nothing else applies.

[Read up on CSS priority](http://hungred.com/useful-information/css-priority-order-tips-tricks/) to see how it works.

Comment: Do you mean physically last in the actual CSS itself, or the last classname in the list?

Comment: He means actually last in the list of all CSS rules defined everywhere, not the order in the attributes list, unfortunately for those using the JavaScript classList methods, who will find this design decision surprising and unhelpful, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Many classes can be assigned to an element, you just separate them with a space

`<div class="myClass aSecondClass keepOnClassing stayClassySanDiego"></div>`

Because of the cascade in CSS, the overwriting rules *closest the to bottom* of the document will be applied to the element.

So if you have

```
.myClass
{
    background: white;
    color: blue;
}

.keepOnClassing
{
    color: red;
}
```

The red color will be used, but not the background color as it was not overwritten.

You must also take into account CSS specificity, if you have a more specific selector, this one will be used:

```
.myClass
{
    background: white;
    color: blue;
}

div.myClass.keepOnClassing
{
    background: purple;
    color: red;
}

.stayClassySanDiego
{
    background: black;
}
```

The second selector here will be used as it is more specific.

You can take a [look at it all here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/KjMad/).

Comment: Upvoted for the best class name of all time 

(as well as being complete and accurate)