# If i have 2 attributes on an element, which one will be displayed?

Tags: html, css, web

If for example an element has 2 classes, both with the color attribute, which one will be displayed?

```
<style>
.red {color:red}
.green{color:green}
</style>

<p class = "red green"> some text </p>
```

DWich color will the text be in this case? What is the rule here? Is it the order of classes in css, or in ? I couldn't figure out a rule in this case.

Comment: Check this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258596/class-overrule-when-two-classes-assigned-to-one-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on how you write your css.**
In your case you have this:

```
<style>
.red {color:red}
.green{color:green}
</style>
```

Which obviously means `.red {color:red}` will apply first and then be overriden by `.green{color:green}`.

So .`green` will win and the color of your text will be green.

***Update:***
*The order of attribute values in the html element does not have effect.*
And when having multiple sylings which wins depends on the [CSS cascading rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html). 
The rule is  inline css wins all the other, and the Head css, and so on...

1.Inline css
2. Head css
3. External css
4. Default css

Comment: If i understand correctly, it is the last declared attribute?
And if i have multiple css files, it is the last imported css file?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it depends on the order of classes, therefore green will be applied. For more information look that [MDN Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> The specificity is calculated on the concatenation of the count of
>   each selectors type. It is a weight that is applied to the
>   corresponding matching expression.
>
> In case of specificity equality, the latest declaration found in the
>   CSS is applied to the element.

Answer (score 0):

The last one(same priority) in style  will be shown because it will override the others while writing it to the element.

so green will be shown in your p tag

```
<p class = "red green"> some text </p>

.red {color:red}
.green{color:green}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0n6a5bn/)

If you change the order the color will be red:-

```
 <p class = "red green"> some text </p>
    .green{color:green}
    .red {color:red}
```

[Fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/jeaa39wd/)
Priority of specific element :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Green will displayed

```
  .green{color:green}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.red {color:red}
.green{color:green}
</style>

<p style="color:blue" class = "red green"> some text </p>
```

The output of above code is in blue color.
The style is applied in this priority order.

inline css > last css class > first css class.

if inline css is missing the last css class attribute overrides the attribute present in other css class before it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just the order in the class in this case. But you have to consider specificity in CSS. The example below will get the first div yellow even though it has classes red and green. It's because an ID is more specific than a class. It would be the same if you added for example parent > div.

```css
#special-div {
    background: yellow;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red green" id="special-div">Test1</div>
<div class="red">Test2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **latter style defined in the stylesheet** is applied to your element. The paragraph will therefore be **green**.

"Specificity" defines, which styles are applied, if there is collisions of styles.

Read more about CSS Specificity here: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ or here http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/specificity/ or even calculate specificity here http://specificity.keegan.st/.