# When multiple css classes are assigned to one element in html

Tags: html, css

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258596/class-overrule-when-two-classes-assigned-to-one-div) . The answer says,

> If the CSS specificity is the same for the conflicting rules, then the
>   later one (the one defined later in the stylesheet or in the later
>   stylesheet) takes precedence.

In the following code, `border1` is the class defined later. So, the div is expected to have a green border. But, how is it getting a black border?

The way I understood the answer might be wrong. Please help to understand this code.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
  .border2{border: 2px solid black};
  .border1{border: 2px solid green};

  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="border1 border2">text</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a syntax error. The semicolon goes after the css attribute and value so it should be `.border2{border: 2px solid black;}` and `.border1{border: 2px solid green;}`.

The question and answer you are referring to above is correct.